# How to make Python Interactive Shell print cyrillic symbols?

Tags: python, shell, unicode, character-encoding, cyrillic

I'm using Pymorphy2 in my project as a cyrillic morphological analyzer.
But when I try to print out the list of words, I get this:

```
>>> for t in terms:
...     p = morph.parse(t)
...     if 'VERB' in p[0].tag:
...             t = p[0].normal_form
...     elif 'NOUN' in p[0].tag:
...             t = p[0].lexeme[0][0]
... 
>>> terms
[u'\u041f\u0430\u0432\u0435\u043b', u'\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442', u'\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0439']
```

How to make it possible to print russian characters in python shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) representation of the unicode strings, if you loop over the list  or index and print each string you will see the output you want.

```
In [4]: terms
Out[4]: 
[u'\u041f\u0430\u0432\u0435\u043b',
 u'\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442',
 u'\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0439'] # repr

In [5]: print terms[0] # str 
Павел

In [6]: print terms[1]
ходит
```

If you want them all printed and to look like a list, use str.format and str.join:

```
terms = [u'\u041f\u0430\u0432\u0435\u043b',
 u'\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442',
 u'\u0434\u043e\u043c\u043e\u0439']

print(u"[{}]".format(",".join(terms)))
```

Output:

```
[Павел,ходит,домой]
```

Comment: But what if I have 1 000 elements in list and would like to see the whole list of words printed out without the redundant iterating over a list?

Comment: When you print list, it's iterated anyway. If you need to print such lists frequently — you can implement ```print_list``` function

Comment: @paus: think about the difference between: `print(unicode_text)` and `print(repr(unicode_text))` (or `print(ascii(unicode_text))` on Python 3). To print the whole list: `for t in terms: print(t)` or `print("\n".join(terms))`. You can't print a list without iterating over it.